# Flask error = Error: Could not import "web_app"

Tags: python-3.x, flask

This error is something that repeatedly and seemingly randomly occurs and I always have difficulty fixing it. I have read all the other posts on this issue and I still can't fix it.

My directory layout is the following

```
> /data
>     .gitignore
>     Pipfile
>     Pipfile.lock
>     README.md
>     run.py
>     /web_app
>         /models
>         /routes
>         /templates
>         init.py
```

Here is init.py

```
from flask import Flask
from web_app.routes.home_routes import home_routes
from web_app.routes.json_routes import json_routes
from web_app.routes.insert_routes import insert_routes

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(home_routes)
app.register_blueprint(json_routes)
app.register_blueprint(insert_routes)

app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is run.py

```
from web_app import app
```

1. I open /data
2. I execute: set FLASK_APP=web_app
3. I execute: run flask
4. I receive this common error:

> Error: Could not import "web_app".

I thought I had perfectly fulfilled the necessary directory design for flask yet it still occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out whats wrong. When I ran flask run in web_app directory, THEN it worked. Though I still don't understand the logic of how flask reads/runs flask directories, so I'm worried it will happen again.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming
**init.py**
file in /data/web_app directory to
**__init__.py**

Comment: This didn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming init.py to `__init__.py` and import as

```
from .web_app import app
```